# How add column from new table in Custom Post Listing (admin)

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development

I'm making an plugin to manage, say, Recipe. I created a table containing informations about my recipes.
I'v created a custom post to add recipe, I know how to add meta box to the post to enter infos stored in my table.
But how can i use some of the informations of my table in the list of my Recipe Custom Post in the admin panel.
How add a join with my table in the query retreiving the posts.

Thanks.

Comment: It would be much more simple to manipulate the administrator area if you used native WordPress functionality and didn't use a custom table.

Answer (score 1):

How to create custom columns for post types: http://justintadlock.com/archives/2011/06/27/custom-columns-for-custom-post-types